# How to hide the Android Keyboard for all activities

Tags: java, android, mobile, keyboard

I want to create an activity that will hide the keyboard. The activity will keep on running in the background as a service and prevent the keyboard from being visible for all the apps. As in the keyboard will not come up unless the activity is stopped. Can anyone point me towards the correct source?

Answer (score 0):

put below code in your manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".View.ViewRegistration"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

I hope its useful to you.and you can  call below method in every activity onresume() and onPause().

```
public static void hideKeyboard(final Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An Activity can not just be kept "running in the background as a service".

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you...

You would need to create an [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). I haven't tried hiding the keyboard via a service, but a wild guess is, that it isn't possible.

A solution could be to create your own keyboard, that the user would then need to switch to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this one line of code in your `manifest` for all those activities where you need to hide the keyboard:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

For example:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.yourappname.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" 
            >
```

Comment: I need the keyboard not to be visible even if the app isn't mine. Like the user just can't access the keyboard no matter what app he is in.